# How can I put a icon inline with paper-input-decorator?

Tags: html, css, polymer

This is what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Although when using this code.

```
<paper-input-decorator floatingLabel label="Name *">
    <core-icon icon="account-circle"></core-icon>
    <input type="name">
</paper-input-decorator>
```

I end up with this,

[image]

I've noticed that in the code on their website ([which can be seen here](http://zephyr.us-themes.com/pages/contact/)) they have just given the form soem padding on the left and then given the icon an absolute position. Is this the only way to do that set up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the polymer layout attributes:

```
<div horizontal layout end>
    <core-icon icon="account-circle" style="margin: 0 10px 10px 0;"></core-icon>
    <paper-input-decorator floatingLabel label="Name *" flex>
        <input type="name">
    </paper-input-decorator>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aswoy1og/

Make sure to import the layout html, e.g.:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/layout.html">
```

Comment: Brilliant just what I was looking for.

Comment: This will no longer work with Polymer 1.0. See the [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#layout-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

include both in a table and give `display: table-cell` to both the icon and input. it will help. then you can style it to cater your need.

Comment: Hi, sounds like it may work although I'm having a problem with the tables as you can see it seems like the polymer elements ignore the table in the html as seen http://i.imgur.com/3z3GqCB.png. Although in the code I have surrounded them. http://i.imgur.com/lVsGIY6.png. I haven't used tables a huge amount so may be missing something obvious

Comment: display: table; and display: table-cell;